# Using SPServices' GetListItems to sort by what the current user has "liked"

Tags: jquery, spservices

I'm using getlistitems to grab list data in SharePoint 2013, and I've managed to be able to filter by the current user's "liked" list items... but is there a way to sort by what a user has liked and show those items first?

CAMLQuery for filtering by current users likes:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LikedBy' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where>
```

Additionally is it possible to use updatelistitems to "like" an item?

Comment: You will want to use the SocialData services, particularly the GetTagsOfUser to see what the user has liked

Comment: Any insight on how to do this? I haven't been able to find many examples of the SocialDataServices and everything I try returns undefined. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this (untested and going from memory):

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetTagsofUser",
  userAccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Name", debug: false}),
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    console.log(xData.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: correction - its GetTagsOfUser 
and this method is depracated